# how do I add simple HTML to panel control which is part of a multiview control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls, dotnetnuke, panel

I have a multi view which contains a view which contains a panel. the name of this panel is "Panel1"

I have the following code and my HTML does not display in the rendered page. Any idea why this isn't working, i must be doing something wrong?
 sw = simple html statement, any would produce same result.

```
 String mstring = sw.ToString();

 Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(mstring));
```

i am using dotnetnuke also, not sure if that is where the issue is.

Comment: Need more info, specifically regarding where you are in the page lifecycle when you call this code ;)

Comment: I simply need to inject html generated from XSLT into a asp.net page on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine.  Are you sure your MultiView is displaying the correct View?

Comment: Actually I needed to add the following to my code behind:

MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

Comment: Given you sent me in the right direction I will treat this as the answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try an alternative work around here?
Just add a literal in the panel like

```
<asp:panel ID="panel1" runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal></panel>
```

and then try

```
lit.Text = sw.ToString();
```

Another interesting check that can help is, sw.ToString() must have something to show. I know this check is crazy but the error is also like that ;)

Comment: Same problem, the HTML is not rendered.